# Incorrect line numbers in gdb with openocd and contiker ng

Tags: arm, gdb, gdbserver, openocd, contiki-ng

I am trying to debug a contiki-ng application running on a LaunchPad CC1312r1 board using OpenOCD. When I add a breakpoint to a line in a source file, gdb gets the line number wrong.

```
(gdb) b packet-send.c:34
Breakpoint 1 at 0x14d46: file ../seneco/communication/udp/packet-send.c, line 60.
```

I have written a small demo application and that works correctly, but I can't get the right line numbers in the application that I am supposed to be debugging.

```
(gdb) b my-cng-example.c:57
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa072: file my-cng-example.c, line 57.
```

I have tried compiling on my native PC and with the contiki-ng docker image. I have tried gdb-multiarch and arm-none-eabi-gdb. I am using the TI repository for OpenOCD, which supports the LaunchPad CC1312r1.

The debugger reports the following compiler flags:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is ../seneco/communication/udp/packet-send.c
Compilation directory is /home/david/gitlab/seneco-contiki-ng/seneco
Located in /home/david/gitlab/seneco-contiki-ng/seneco/communication/udp/packet-send.c
Contains 65 lines.
Source language is c.
Producer is GNU C99 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -march=armv7e-m -g -O0 -Os -std=c99 -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines I was trying to set breakpoints on were removed by preprocessor defines. gdb just sets the breakpoint on the next valid line.